# Python - Is there a way to replace a string when it's mixed with uppercase and lowercase letters?

Tags: python, string, replace, zip

If a word has d' or 's in it, I want to replace it with d'$ and $'s.

Using word.lower(), it was completed to check whether the capitalized word contains d' and 's. However, I don't know how to replace capitalized strings with d'$ and $'s.
Is there a way to change it **without using regex**?

```py
x = "D'you d'yeh IT'S she's love"
x = x.split()

b = ["d'", "'s"]
a = ["d'$", "$'s"]
y = x
for b, a in zip(b, a):
    y = [word.replace(b, a) if b in word.lower() else word for word in y]

print(y)
```

The current result is as follows.

```py
["D'you", "d'$yeh", "IT'S", "she$'s", 'love']
```

The result I want is as follows.

```py
["D'$you", "d'$yeh", "IT$'S", "she$'s", 'love']
```

Thanks very much for your help...

Comment: why have you specified "without using regex", is there a particular reason why shouldn't we use it?

Comment: This is because only the default built-in functions are available.

Comment: RE is available in Python 3 by default. Yes you have to import it but it's an inherent part of Python

Comment: Umm... This means that there is a condition that the regex module is not available in the problem

Comment: Your python installation is broken. You should fix that instead of working around the brokenness.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to tokenise and print a list but here goes anyway:

```
x = "D'you d'yeh IT'S she's love"

for a, b in [("D'", "D'$"), ("'S", "$'S"), ("d'", "d'$"), ("'s", "$'s")]:
    x = x.replace(a, b)

print(x.split())
```

**Output:**

```
["D'$you", "d'$yeh", "IT$'S", "she$'s", 'love']
```